# Bulk loop renaming file contents from list in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace

I have a little script that I'm testing but cant seem to get the output to work correctly.

I've got a whole lot of markdown files with URLs in them and an array that gets built of dead urls (they're internal links not public).

```js
const urls = [
 'http://internal.site1.com',
 'https://internal.site2.com',
 'http://internal.site3.com/file.html',
 'https://internal.site4.com/dir/'
];

const markdown = [
 './file1.md',
 './file2.md',
 './sub/file3.md',
 './sub/sub/file4.md',
];
```

And I'm looping the markdown files from an array, then trying to replace the `url` from the data returned:

```js
for( const md of markdown ) {
  var mdFileContents = fs.readFileSync( md, 'utf8' );
  for( const url of urls ) {
    var result = mdFileContents.replaceAll( url, '[X]' );
    // also tried: var result = mdFileContents.replace( new RegExp( url, "g" ), "[X]" );
  }
}
```

Except when this runs, and I do a `console.log(result);` I either get no replacements, or I only get one url (on one file) out of all the files replaced.

My test markdown files are in the vein of:

```
HTTP URL:  http://internal.site1.com
HTTPS URL: https://internal.site2.com

[md shortcode](http://internal.site3.com/file.html)
[mb shortcode](https://internal.site4.com/dir/)
```

With one test `md` file with no matching urls. The script results come out as:

```
HTTP URL:  [X]
HTTPS URL: https://internal.site2.com

[md shortcode](http://internal.site3.com/file.html)
[mb shortcode](https://internal.site4.com/dir/)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or in the wrong order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first start the loop for the files. Then per file, loop the urls and run:

```
var result = mdFileContents.replaceAll( url, '[X]' );
```

So per url, you re-read the file contents (which is still as is, unmodified) and you replace the matching url with `[X]`

Now when you run `console.log(result);` you will see a single replacement only as you are re-reading the file contents every time.

You could read the contents per file in for exampele `mdFileContents`, and then do the replacements for all the urls reusing `mdFileContents` until all replacements are done.

**Note** That your urls contain a dot. When you pass the string to the RegExp constructor, you have to double escape the dot `\\.` to match it literally or else the dot will match any character except a newline.

```
let mdFileContents = fs.readFileSync( md, 'utf8' );

for( const url of urls ) {
    mdFileContents = mdFileContents.replace( new RegExp( url, "g" ), "[X]" );
}
console.log(mdFileContents);
```

Comment: that makes perfect sense - cant believe I didn't see it!

Comment: @markb No worries, it happens :-) Good luck!